# Browser not recognizing struts2 tag

Tags: html, struts2

I am designing a simple html page. I am using struts2 tags. The code is as follows

```
<style>
    acronym[title] {
     border-bottom-width: 0;
    }
</style>
<span>
   <a class="imageLink grow" href="<s:url action="uploadLink"/>">
   <acronym title="Upload"><img src="images/upload.png" width="80px" height="80px" alt="Upload"/></acronym></a>
</span>
```

The resultant output is

[image]
I don't understand why *">* is being printed. If I remove that strut2 tag in 'href' then the problem is not there. Can anyone tell me what is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because you are using " " for `href` you need to use ' ' to wrap the action. Otherwise you will escape the command

```
<a class="imageLink grow" href="<s:url action='uploadLink'/>">
```

Comment: This can't be the right answer. `<s:url />` is evaluated serverside, and substituted before rendering the HTML. The result will be `href="myActualUrl"` no matter which kind of quotes you use. ??? This is useful to prevent Eclipse to break syntax coloring, though.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

Try this instead:

```
<a class="imageLink grow" href="/abc/actionname.action">
```

There's an error in your code, extra html "> after the a class

```
<style>
    acronym[title] {
     border-bottom-width: 0;
    }
</style>
<span>
   <a class="imageLink grow" href="<s:url action="uploadLink"/>"> <!-- LOOK HERE -->
   <acronym title="Upload"><img src="images/upload.png" width="80px" height="80px" alt="Upload"/></acronym></a>
</span>
```

Comment: " is for closing href. > is for closing a.